# Understanding the life cycle of BindingContext in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I have a basic registration page when the user register her data, I save an object of this data in a static field of the `Settings` static class , so I can fill the common fields with other registration pages, like `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`...etc. so the user doesn't have to re-fill them again.

the very specific case I have is, one of these common pages is the basic registration page itself (with some fields excluded).
first that's how the common fields look like:

```xml
<Entry Text="{Binding RegistrationData.first_name, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="{Resx:TranslateExtension Text=lbFirstName}"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding RegistrationData.last_name, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="{Resx:TranslateExtension Text=lbLastName}"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding RegistrationData.email, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Email"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="{Resx:TranslateExtension Text=lbEmail}"/>
```

apparently the model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

in the constructor of the Register page:

```cs
public Register(int userType) //when I call this constructor the registration page represent some sub-registration pages
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var oRegistrationViewModel = (RegistrationViewModel)BindingContext;
    if (Settings.UserData != null)
    {     
        oRegistrationViewModel.RegistrationData = Settings.UserData;
        BindingContext = oRegistrationViewModel;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, when I reset the `BindingContext` the data is not bound to the fields.

I set the `Settings.UserData` in the `OnRegister` method of the `RegisterCommand` in the view-model, when called from the basic page (with default constructor)

I'm using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight`
I set the BindingContext in XAML:

```xml
BindingContext="{Binding Register, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

the `Locator` is a key of the `ViewModelLocator`, in the constructor:

```cs
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<RegistrationViewModel>();
```

and this property:

```cs
public RegistrationViewModel Register
{
    get
    {
        return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<RegistrationViewModel>();
    }
}
```

I need to know when the `BindingContext` is set with binding in XAML, Is this happen when calling `InitializeComponent()`,  when I called it after resetting the `BindingContext` the data still not shown.

Comment: `OnBindingContextChanged` event might help you, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37872231/199364).